# How to find the nth term in quadratic sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

[image]

Consider this triangular set of numbers. Determine the last number in the $99$th row.

I came up with the formula for the $n$'th term, and got $\frac{1}{2}n^{2} +\frac{1}{2}n$

The issue is that the last term in the $99$th row is not the last term. So the $3$rd overall term is the last term of the second row, the 6th overall term is the last term in the third row, and the $10$th overall term is the last in the fourth row, etc.

So the pattern is $3,6,10, \dots$ and the formula for $a_{n} = \frac{1}{2}n^{2}+1.5n+1$

My issue is, how can I find out what term number the last number of the $99$th term is? that way I can find out what $n$ is to plug into my original equation

Answer (score 3):

Hint. The last term of the $r$-th row is $n$-th [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) where
$$n=1+2+3+\dots+r.$$

Comment: Beat me to it! You phrased it better than a I could have anyway :) $+1$

Comment: oh wow. I feel so dumb. so it's just $1+2+...+99$. My question is, how can I just look at this and recognize it? I'm having trouble recognizing what to do. Let's say the numbers were not triangular, then what would I do?

Comment: @Clayton Thanks for your comment!

Comment: "Let's say the numbers were not triangular" What do you mean? Have you any example to propose?

Comment: If I do this ,then I get $a_{99} = \frac{99}{2}(1+99)$ and that is 4950. but that seems way too buy, what did I do wrong?

Comment: @user8290579 Actually you should evaluate $n=4950$ and therefore you have to evaluate $a_{4950}$. For example the last number in the $4$th row is $a_{10}=\frac{10\cdot 11}{2}=55$.

Comment: wait maybe I'm missing something, so my formula for finding any term $\frac{1}{2}n^{2}+\frac{1}{2}n$ is not even relevant here? because I can just do $1+2+...+99$

Comment: so i need to evaluate $a_{4950}$ in $\frac{1}{2}n^{2}_\frac{1}{2}n$?

Comment: Yes, it is relevant, but you have to use it two times. One time to evaluate $n=r(r+1)/2$ and then to evaluate $a_n=n(n+1)/2$. Is it clear now?

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, what I need to do is: $n = 99(99+1)/2 = 4950$ and then $\frac{1}{2}(4950)^{2} + \frac{1}{2}(4950)$ and that is my answer?

Comment: I get 12,253,725. That's an enormous number

Comment: Yes, that's correct.